# Selecting Multiple Columns Using Header names - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a requirement where I need to select Multiple columns using only the header names and this is my code for that ,

```
colmz = WorksheetFunction.Match("Sheet1", Sheets("Age").Rows(1), 0)
Nrowz = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, colmz).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("sheet1").Range(Cells(1, colmz), Cells(Nrowz, colmz)).Select

colm = WorksheetFunction.Match("Sheet1", Sheets("Gender").Rows(1), 0)
Sheets("sheet1").Range(Cells(1, colm), Cells(Nrowz, colm)).Select
```

I was able to select them individually but not together. How do I use them inside the range function and select both the columns together. Kindly give me your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only select one by one so if you use 2 "select", the first one will become useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select the `UNION` of the two ranges. For clarity, I've created ranges for the two areas to `.select`. Using this method allows you to specify the Sheet to use also.

```
Dim age_range, gender_range As Range

colmz = WorksheetFunction.Match("Sheet1", Sheets("Age").Rows(1), 0)
Nrowz = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, colmz).End(xlUp).Row
colm = WorksheetFunction.Match("Sheet1", Sheets("Gender").Rows(1), 0)

Set age_range = Sheets("sheet1").Range(Cells(1, colmz), Cells(Nrowz, colmz))
Set gender_range = Sheets("sheet1").Range(Cells(1, colm), Cells(Nrowz, colm))

Sheets("sheet1").Range(Union(age_range, gender_range).Address).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Union function and it did work for me

```
Union(Range(Cells(1, colmz), Cells(Nrowz, colmz)), Range(Cells(1, colm), Cells(Nrowz, colm))).Select
```

kindly let me know, if there is a better practice than this

Comment: well it depends on different things : Are you doing this only once or you will repeat this code multiple times ? If so, are the columns you want to select always called by those 2 header names or not ?

Comment: @Seb I don't have to use it again and again. I only need to use them once. but still, I think I will still go with the Answer provided by CLR